# Need a formula to solve for X

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that would include a variable. h2/3.5%=80%/x

Background: 70% is the lowest score 150% is the highest. If you receive a 150% you get 3.5% if you get 70% you get 0% I need this formula to figure out everything in between.

I (hope) included a picture of my sheet and what I am looking for perspective. (the formula and data that are in I are completely incorrect.)

[image]

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with programming. However…

y = (x - 70%) / (150% - 70%) * (3.5% - 0%) + 0%

Comment: I need a formula for my raise 3.5% column, What is there is incorrect. I need a formula to calculate what their raise would be based on the information I provided.

Comment: @ominug ... it's a little fuzzy, see for example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic

Comment: I don't understand how asking how to build a certain formula is not a valid question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a straight relationship, you may try the following formula:

```
=IF(B1<=0.7,0,IF(B1>=1.5,0.035,(B1-0.7)*(3.5/80)))
```

It caters for numbers outside the range, and also gives 110% a value of 1.75% (i.e. a value halfway in the input range gives an outcome halfway up the output range).

Regards,

Comment: thank you, When I place this in, it gives me every row at 4%. I need it to be exact.

Comment: Have you changed the cell reference? What are the actual numbers in the cells, and how are they formatted?